# Crop area from image using Pillow in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

[image: Rectangle with lines which are not parallel to the margins]

I want to crop a rectangle shape area from an image using Pillow in python. The problem is that the rectangle is not necessary parallel with the image margins so I cannot use the .crop((left, top, right, bottom)) function.

Is there a way to achieve this with Pillow? (assuming we know the coordinates of all 4 points of rectangle) 
If not, how it can be done using a different Python library?

[image: The end result should look like this]

Comment: Please provide the coordinates you presumably have for the corners. How do you expect the result to look?

Comment: What would you expect to get? the image with black pixels outside the rectangle? or a rectified image?

Answer (score 2):

You can use min rotated rectangle in OpenCV:

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
```

As a result You have: center coordinates (x,y), width, height, angle of rotation of rectangle. You can rotate whole image with angle from this rectangle. You image now will be rotated:

[image: Rotated image]

You can calculate new coordinates of four rectangle vertices (you got angle). Then just calculate normal rectangle for this points (normal rectangle = not minimal, without any rotation). With this rect You can crop Your rotated image. In this crop image will be what You want if I understand You correctly. Something like that:

[image: result]

So You only need Opencv. Maybe there is some library with which You can do it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution based on scikit-image (not Pillow) that you might find useful.

You could pass the vertices of the region you wish to crop to the function [`skimage.draw.polygon`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon) and then use the retrieved pixel coordinates to mask the original image (for example, through the alpha channel).

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, draw

img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Ym4.png')

vertices = np.asarray([[150, 140],
                       [300, 240],
                       [210, 420],
                       [90, 320],
                       [150, 150]])

rows, cols = draw.polygon(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1])

crop = img.copy()
crop[:, :, -1] = 0
crop[rows, cols, -1] = 255

io.imshow(crop)
```

[image: Masked image]

Answer (score 0):

I adapted [this `opencv`-based solution (`sub_image`)](https://github.com/martinjevans/OpenCV-Rotate-and-Crop/blob/master/rotate_and_crop.py#L15) for use with `PIL`. It takes a `(center, size, theta)` rect which I'm getting from `cv2.minAreaRect`, but could be constructed mathmatically from points, etc.

I've seen a few other solutions but they left some weird artifacts.

```py
     
def crop_tilted_rect(image, rect):
    """ crop rect out of image, handing rotation
    
    rect in this case is a tuple of ((center_x, center_y), (width, height), theta),
    which I get from opencv's cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
    """
    # Get center, size, and angle from rect
    center, size, theta = rect
    width, height = [int(d) for d in size]

    if 45 < theta <= 90:
        theta = theta - 90
        width, height = height, width

    theta *= math.pi / 180 # convert to rad
    v_x = (math.cos(theta), math.sin(theta))
    v_y = (-math.sin(theta), math.cos(theta))
    s_x = center[0] - v_x[0] * (width / 2) - v_y[0] * (height / 2)
    s_y = center[1] - v_x[1] * (width / 2) - v_y[1] * (height / 2)
    mapping = np.array([v_x[0],v_y[0], s_x, v_x[1],v_y[1], s_y])
    return image.transform((width, height), Image.AFFINE, data=mapping, resample=0, fill=1, fillcolor=(255,255,255))
```