# python to crop and save irregular image or crop and place it in the centre without resizing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, image-compression

I am working for image comparison for which I need to make a template.

current Image:

[image: original image]

I am able to colour the required image but not able to crop the image required, the code to colour image is as follow :

```html
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('./org.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    print (len(approx))
    if len(approx)==5:
        # print "pentagon"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,-1)
    elif len(approx)==3:
        # print "triangle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),-1)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        # print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),-1)
    elif len(approx) == 9:
        # print "half-circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),-1)
    elif len(approx) > 15:
        # print "circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),-1)

cv2.imwrite('./test/Image_crop.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

OUTPUT :

[image: output image]

1. I want to crop the image which is coloured **red**.
2. Save the crop image with **irregular** Dimenstion.
3. Is there any other way round to get the required image rather than **cv2.drawContours**

The question Depends on : [Python libraries failed for detailed image comparison between two shifted images captured using webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590050/python-libraries-failed-for-detailed-image-comparison-between-two-shifted-images)

help me for the solution using **python**.

Comment: *Save the crop image with irregular Dimenstion* ? I don't think it would be possible as image is generally considered as `mxn` matrix However you can use alpha channel to hide some parts of image but it is always going to be perfect rectangle.

Comment: @ZdaR I will try alpha channel

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522956/crop-area-from-image-using-pillow-in-python/54533879#54533879).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `mask` from the contour and using this mask to copy from the original Image and then you can save the image.

```
cv::Mat dst;
originalIamge.copyTo(dst, mask);
cv::imwite("path/where/to/save.jpg", dst);
```

**Update:** *In more details*.

Create a bounding box from the counter `cv::boundingRect(contour)`

```
cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contour);
```

And now you can use this rect get a submat from the original Image

```
cv::Mat roi = img(rect);
```

And then create a new `Mat` the same size as the `ROI`

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::create(roi.size(), CV_8UC3);
```

And create a mask

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::drawContours(mask, contours, 0, cv::Scalar(255), cv::FILLED);
mask = mask(roi);
```

Now you can copy the required part of the image by using the mask

```
roi .copyTo(dst, mask);
```

And save

```
cv::imwite("path/where/to/save.jpg", dst);
```

Comment: The code is almost the same, you can just do the steps as I mentioned.

Comment: I am stuck in create a mask, as their is no mask function for `mask = mask(roi);` also want to know what do you mean by mask ??

Comment: mask is not a function, mask is declared here `cv::Mat mask`. mask is used to copy the part of the image which you detected the color there. So mask tells to copyTo function that only copy these pixels. otherwise, the whole image will be copied.

Comment: only thing left is I am unable to make irregular border as I am using `cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)' in python which is use to make rectangle over the object. any alternative for `cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)` which will provide me to make irregular border over the object.

Comment: There is no irregular border image at all.

Comment: Is there any way to check the neighbouring pixel value, for image comparison ??? to compare current pixel value with neighbouring pixel value